# Telerik RadSearchBox is not working for large data

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I need to access with large data around 10000 records as data source. So when i type a text to filter only the contained text should be in drop down list. But in my solution it shows all of the records in drop down list.

Comment: can you share code?

Comment: No i can't. Can you please do it in your way its helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using `Filter="Contains"` property in your `RadSearchBox`. Just follow this sample. You can also use `Filter="StartWith"`. Without this property you ALWAYS get all data.

**DataModel**

```
  public class Test
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
    }
```

**Create DataSource and set it to SearchBox**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Test> test = new List<Test>();
        test.Add(new Test() {firstName = "Adam", lastName = "Nowak"});
        test.Add(new Test() { firstName = "Jan",lastName = "Kowalski"});
        test.Add(new Test() { firstName = "Piotr", lastName = "Mały" });
        test.Add(new Test() { firstName = "Kazimierz", lastName = "Wąski" });
        RadSearchBox1.DataSource = test;


    }
```

**and SearchBox**

```
<telerik:RadSearchBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="RadSearchBox1"
                  CssClass="searchBox" Skin="Silk"
                  Width="460" DropDownSettings-Height="300"
                  DataTextField="lastName"
                  EmptyMessage="Search"
                  Filter="Contains"
                  MaxResultCount="20">
```

Comment: Thanks for your time mww. But still issue is there. because of large data